# How to use Word to edit documents in a database

Tags: c#, database, wpf, ms-office

This may be completely impossible, but I'll ask anyway :)

In our application we save all our data in a database (no surprises there). Among other thing we have some documents saved, and lets the user edit these documents using an in-build editor we have.

We would like to replace this with Microsoft Word (we don't have be backward compatible, so just forget about the existing documents).

Ideally I would like a functionality similar to OneDrive or SharePoint. The user finds the document in my application, opens in Word, and changes are automatically save back to where the document was opened from.

Having looked at `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` I'm able to open and edit Word files, but I need to save to the database (I think a stream would suffice. I think I'll be able to redirect that to the database). Anyone that knows of a way to open a stream instead?

I have also looked at `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing` which seems to give me the handles to edit Word documents even from streams, but I would really like to open in the Word application, and not have to reimplement Word from scratch.

The application is written in C# with WPF if it matters :)

Yours
/peter

Comment: Not impossible - unclear. Databases store stuff, they don't edit documents. Neither SharePoint nor OneDrive edit word documents either, they use the Word Online editor component, or the Office Web Apps component in earlier SharePoint versions. *None* of these use Word itself.

Comment: You could save the word .docx file into a [temporary file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=netframework-4.8), read the [file in binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=netframework-4.8) and put it into the database as a [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). Then to edit it, do the opposite, get binary from DB, save into a temporary file and open it in word.

Comment: If the question is `How do I store documents in a database?` you'll have to specify the database product and version. All databases offer BLOB storage but that's not necessarily the best option. Many databases offer storage outside the table data files themselves, and even remote storage. SQL Server for example offers FILESTREAM storage outside the data tables themselves,FileTables or Remote BLOB Storage for storing large documents in specialized storage devices.

Comment: Check [Compare Options for Storing Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/remote-blob-store-rbs-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for the various options and a comparison

Comment: The required scenario is not entirely clear. One of the things that you could do is implement an Office Add-in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/

Comment: BTW with FILESTREAM storage you can use normal file IO to work with the file

Comment: Thank Longood12000. I was hoping it was possible to avoid an "intermediate" file, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos the connection to the database is not the problem. The problem was how to avoid saving to a file

Comment: Write to the Blob's stream. You don't need to save anything locally. Even with BLOBs, ADO.NET offers a stream interface. With FILESTREAM though, that stream connects to a real file on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to go:

- save the Word document to a temporary folder, launch Word from your app specifying the location as a command-line argument; once the document is closed (watch for the lock file Word creates), save it back to your back-end storage;
- implement WebDAV or any other protocol Word supports for connecting to document management systems (such as SharePoint).

The second option leads to a rather large development effort and/or use of 3rd party libraries that may implement such functionality. Should you consider developing it yourself, I'd start from Microsoft's [open specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/openspecs/office_protocols/ms-offprotlp/5859f0f1-a929-475b-9b23-554994675456).